# How to add helper to view helpers?

Tags: view, symfony1, symfony-1.4

As in title: How to add helper to view helpers? so I can use it without loading custom helpers group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the settings.yml to auto load helpers. Don't forget to add the default ones (Partial, Cache) too or they won't be loaded.
For example:

```
all:
  .settings:
    standard_helpers: [Partial, Cache, MyCustomHelper]
```

http://www.symfonyreference.com/ is a good site for symfony configuration reference.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the ["gentle introduction" to Symfony 1.4](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers)

> The list of the standard helpers, loaded by default for every
>   template, is configurable in the **settings.yml** file.

It will avoid to call `use_helper()` on all of your templates (if I have correctly understood your question).

Comment: In **apps/frontend/config/settings.yml** you can add your custom helper: `standard_helpers:[I18N,  Partial, Date, YourHelper]`.

Comment: Here's the 1.4 link: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers